# web method for dataset-web service on android/eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, web-services

How to create a web method for the web service which is returning the values as "dataset" by consuming it from android.

Is this web-method right?

```
public class GetName {

    public DataSet GetName(String str) {
        return str;
    }
}
```

If not please let me now any idea or sample sources.I have googled it as per my knowledge but still searching for solution.

Thanks for your precious time!

Comment: You solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this link [Create java based web service in Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BottomUpAxis2WebService/bu_tutorial.html) it will help you to create java based web service and if you have problem in that you can write me.